# What's the meaning of the red-colored text in the TOP information

Tags: ubuntu

When I type the `top` command in the Ubuntu 14.04

I saw some red color information, But I didn't know what's the meaning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Top itself dosen't have any colours by default (you hit z to switch, and the colours I see are the reverse of yours) and , and its configurable. As such they don't mean anything on their own.

However, as per the [manpage for top](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top)

```
  Task_Area:  Tasks running (or ready to run) will be highlighted, and
  bold is only one way of emphasizing such processes.
```

Which is what I believe is the case here.